# INSERTED data via SQL command does not show correctly in comboBox1

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I have a problem where after I insert data into my SQL Lite database the `combobox1` doesnt refresh to show the data correctly. After I insert my data I simply call the following method:

```
void fillcomboBox1()
{
    if (m_dbConnection != null && m_dbConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        m_dbConnection.Open();
    }

    SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter("select * from rdpdirectory order by company asc", m_dbConnection);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    da.Fill(dt);

    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i]["Company"]);
    }
    m_dbConnection.Close();
}
```

My insert code looks like this:

```
    void InsertConnectionDetails()

    {
        if (m_dbConnection != null && m_dbConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            m_dbConnection.Open();
        }



        string sql = @"insert into rdpdirectory (company, server, username, password) 
                   values (@company, @server, @username,@password)";

        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company", txtCompany.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@server", txtServer.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUserName.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        m_dbConnection.Close();
        fillcomboBox1();
        comboBox1.Refresh();
        MessageBox.Show("Done");

}
```

I thought the idea was to fill the datatable again and the combobox should show the values? The problem specifically is  that i see duplicates of the same value but when i restart the app, the correctly inserted values show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem :** You are adding the Items into Combobox everytime you call the `fillcomboBox1()` method.

so if you call the `fillcomboBox1()` method two times ComboBox will surley will have the duplicate items as you are adding items twice.

**Solution :** You need to clear the Items from ComboBox before adding Items.
 You can use `comboBox1.Items.Clear()` method to clear all existing items from the `Combobox` before adding items into it.

Add the following statement into `fillcomboBox1()` method.

```
comboBox1.Items.Clear();
```

**Complete Code:**

```
void fillcomboBox1()
{
comboBox1.Items.Clear();// <---Add this statement
if (m_dbConnection != null && m_dbConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    m_dbConnection.Open();
}

SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter("select * from rdpdirectory order by company asc", m_dbConnection);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

da.Fill(dt);

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i]["Company"]);
}
m_dbConnection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

bind the comboBox1 as below

```
void fillcomboBox1()
{
    // your code .....

    da.Fill(dt);
    comboBox1.DataSource = dt; // set DataSource  as your DataTable
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Company"; // you only need to set the display column name
    m_dbConnection.Close();
}
```

otherwise you need to clear the items befor adding new items